# How do you use hiearchy datatype with ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I'm trying to model a hierarchy using the new hierarchy data type in SQL Server 2008.  When I move the table into my EF model, the hierarchy column doesn't show up as something that can be mapped or as a property in the entity.

Because I'm using ASP.NET MVC, I'm using the EF framework as the primary way to access data.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 1):

Most UDTs (including HierarchyID) etc can be hacked into the EF as binary.

You have to manually add the column to the SSDL (essentially lying to the EF)

Check [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2008/02/25/all-the-power-at-your-disposal.aspx) out for more

Hope this helps
Alex